# How to get/set data of(into) visual components (of windows programs) programmatically?

Tags: c#, java, python, windows, impersonation

I am talking about windows GUI programs. Say a program-window has a dialog box (or a confirm button) asking user input. How can I provide input to that program using my program (written in say C#, Java or Python). Or say, a program window is showing some image in one of its panels. How can I grab that from other(my) program. It is a kind of impersonating (or inter-win-program messaging?). Someone told me it can be done using spy++. But how? Can you explain? What code to write? What to do with spy++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

spy++ is listening for all win32 messages. It is very useful for debugging an application but I don't think that it is a good idea to use it as an inter-process communication mechanism.

You can use win32 apis to send input to your program. As an example, You can modify the content of an edit text by using the [SetWindowText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633546%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.

You need to get the handle of the window. You can use the FindWindow and the GetDlgItem to get it.

It will work for c++ and python thanks to [win32 python extension](http://python.net/crew/mhammond/win32/Downloads.html). I don't know if there it is possible to use win32 api from java.

Answer (score 1):

To programmatically generate key presses, see [Key Presses in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136734/key-presses-in-python), and search for "generate", "key", "emulate", "fake".

To programmatically capture the screen, see [Capture screenshot of active window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163761/c-capture-screenshot-of-active-window), and search for terms like "capture", "window", "screen".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write win32 code to do it, start here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632589(VS.85).aspx

If you just want to hook the gui as easily as possible, investigate:

http://www.winbatch.com/

http://www.autoitscript.com/

http://www.autohotkey.com/