# Python Simulate Keypress in Flash Application

Tags: python

There is a form in a flash application that I would like to fill out automatically. I did a search, and found this:

[Key Presses in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136734/key-presses-in-python)

That works fine for notepad and such, but how do I grab a flash object running in FireFox, simulate pressing characters, and also simulate pressing ENTER for moving to the next field?

**EDIT**

Actually, do you even need to grab the flash object in the first place? Why not just simulate the keypresses directly?

Anyways, if it helps any...

Windows 7 Home Edition,
Python 2.4

Comment: I would be interested to know if this was possible.  I would guess you would need to hack/decomplie the swf to do it?

Comment: This guy did something similar. Mathletics is a flash game: http://www.importsoul.net/category/python/thinkquick/

Comment: Thanks for the little shout out, when i wrote the program i also made a few changes to it to make it simpler to use but i dont know where that code has gone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works perfectly: http://www.rutherfurd.net/python/sendkeys

Comment: yeah that's good, i've already try it. but we need python 2.6 or older version.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible via the [Selenium testing framework](http://seleniumhq.org/) with a special [Flash extension](http://code.google.com/p/flash-selenium/) for letting selenium talk to Flash in the browser. The Python client is in the [downloads section](http://code.google.com/p/flash-selenium/downloads/list).

Here is [an article walking through an example](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/flash_selenium.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader_1) (the sample client code is in Java, but should also work with the Python client).