# Python acting as a keyboard

Tags: python, keyboard, python-2.7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Key Presses in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136734/key-presses-in-python)

I want to know if there is a easy way to make python act as a keyboard. I have a CNC mill that runs off a windows machine using Mach 3.

I want to create a python script that will jog the mill for me. To jog the mill you just press buttons on a keyboard to move normally.

So is there a python library that will act as a keyboard in a different program?

Answer (score 2):

If you must use python, try [pywinauto](http://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/) or [AutoPy](http://www.autopy.org/).

I prefer [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) or [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

Comment: Thnx i will look in to them tomorrow