# Interact with the UI of an application in python

Tags: python

I want to open a program and interact very briefly with the UI of it. For now I managed to open the program with this line:

```
subprocess.call([r"C:\Users\path\to\program\program.exe", "first-parameter", "second-parameter"])
```

The program displays at the start a small warning box with the button "Ok".
I would like to simulate a key press "Enter" so that the program moves on.
I tried to implement it like it was explained in in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136734/key-presses-in-python):

```
import subprocess
import win32com.client as comctl

wsh = comctl.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")

subprocess.call([r"C:\Users\path\to\program\program.exe", "first-parameter", "second-parameter"])
wsh.AppActivate("program.exe")
wsh.SendKeys("{Enter}")
```

The SendKeys() argument was not reached until I closed the program.exe.
After I closed the program.exe the "Enter" key got pressed.

Is there a way to interact with the UI of program.exe or do the KeyPress() so it gets reached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To NOT wait for you program to exit you need to use `subprocess.Popen` instead of `subprocess.call`. More info in python docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor).

Hope this helps!