# OBS doesn't receive hotkey from python script

Tags: python, hotkeys, pynput, obs

I am trying to do automatic scene changer in OBS by having a python script search for a specific image on screen. When the image is detected, the python script will send the hotkey, which should be picked by OBS (Same hotkey added in program).

However, I tried this in various applications like chrome/notepad/some games/etc and the hotkeys DO get "transmitted", but OBS doesn't pick them up. I don't know why, any help ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From this thread: [Key Presses in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136734/key-presses-in-python)

It seems like you need to install pywin32 module.
With that you can send key presses to other applications:

```
import win32com.client as comclt
wsh= comclt.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
wsh.AppActivate("Notepad") # select another application
wsh.SendKeys("a") # send the keys you want
```