# python: what library can simulate type

Tags: python

I wanted to have a simple python script to keep repeat typing certain words and send.
like have an idle game and need leave it open and using skills. Is there any library can do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Key Presses in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136734/key-presses-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a pynput library. Just simply install it and there are many videos teaching how to do so. This is an example if the simulation and just edit it to different key or words.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time

keyboard = Controller()
interval = 1.5
times = 9
counter = times

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    if counter == times:
        keyboard.type(';h')
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)
        keyboard.release(Key.enter)
        time.sleep(interval)
        keyboard.type(';f')
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)
        keyboard.release(Key.enter)
        time.sleep(interval)
        keyboard.type(';wings')
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)
        keyboard.release(Key.enter)
        time.sleep(interval)
        keyboard.type(';rage')
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)
        keyboard.release(Key.enter)
        time.sleep(interval)
        keyboard.type(';earthquake')
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)
        keyboard.release(Key.enter)
        counter = 0
        time.sleep(interval)
        for i in range(20):
            keyboard.type(';s')
            keyboard.press(Key.enter)
            keyboard.release(Key.enter)
            time.sleep(3)
        
    else:
        counter += 1
    time.sleep(interval)
    keyboard.type(';s')
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    time.sleep(interval)
    time.sleep(30)
```

Comment: Wow it really works so easily. Thanks Aaron.