# Key pressing in python doesn't work properly (in UCN game bot)

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, keyboard, bots

I wrote this code in python3 to cheat the game FNaF : UCN so whenever I'm pressing and holding down the right click button, it'll keep pressing `c` and `<enter>` both together, getting me rid of two annoying game mechanics. Here's the code:

```
import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
Keyboard = Controller()
from pynput.mouse import Listener, Button
import threading
import time
Held = False
def pressEnter():
    while Held: # While I'm holding down the button
        Keyboard.press(Key.enter) # Press <enter>
        Keyboard.press(key="c") # Press "c"
        print("Pressing...\n", Held)
        time.sleep(0.1)
def easier_Enter(x, y, butt, held):
    global Held
    Held = held
    if (butt == Button.right) and held:
        threading.Thread(target=pressEnter, daemon=True, args=()).start()
    else: print("Stopped.")
def listener1():
    while True:
        with Listener(on_click=easier_Enter) as l:
            l.join()
def main():
    threading.Thread(target=listener1, daemon=True, args=()).start()
    print("Thread 1 started.")
    while not keyboard.is_pressed('x'):
        try:
            pass
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            getOut()
    getOut()
def getOut():
    print("Exitted.")
    quit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

When I run the script, it works just as expected and when I hold down the button, it starts pressing those two keys. **However though**, it doesn't really work while I'm **IN THE GAME** which is the whole purpose of the program. It's like it's only working on 1 window.

How can I make it work on the game window as well?

Comment: This is a very popular problem, where things don't work in a different platforms. I would recommend, before anything else, NOT pressing keys one at a time. With `keyboard` at least, you can do both at the same time, like this: `keyboard.press('enter+c')`. Another thing-how are you testing this? When you were on that one window that worked, how did you know it worked? This might help show if this has to do with the game window or not.

Comment: Just tested the method you said, still doesn't work. And I found out that it works because I ran the script on my terminal and once I terminated the process, the terminal gave me errors like `'c' is not a command...` and so on, also my program prints out if it pressed the buttons or not, also while I was testing it on the game itself, it printed that it's working but it actually wasn't.

Comment: I would still recommend testing it some other way. For example, open up a simple web browser game, like something that requires pressing arrow keys or whatever, and try your program. If that still doesn't work, I would STRONGLY recommend taking a look at [pyautogui](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/) as I've tested it myself, and it has worked in several platforms without trouble.

Comment: Oh! I almost fixed it!!! by editing it a little bit: `        keyboard.press_and_release('c')
        time.sleep(0.1)
        keyboard.press_and_release('enter')` It works properly now! but there's a little issue here.. it doesn't press the keys *in time* like it lags out a little bit and sometimes it takes it a little bit more to press those keys after I hold the right click, could I fix these as well?

Comment: Alright then! gonna test it with pyautogui.

Comment: I would especiallly recommend the `keyDown()` and `keyUp()` functions in `pyautogui` if you're going to test it. Or `pyautogui.hotkey()` can press multiple keys at a time.

Comment: So, here's what I experienced using pyautogui(pag): the `pag.press()` function looked 3 times slower than the keyboard's press function, although `keyDown()` & `keyUp()` presented a better result overall, although I'm still always losing to the "Old Man Consequences" character that requires you to catch his fish by spamming the `c` button to catch it when it hits the rod. i tried decreasing the waiting time from `0.1` to `0.01` and this made me lose to the other one as well for some reason xd.

Comment: Hmm. That's to be expected, since it's kind of hard to work with off platform games. Out of interest, what system do you have and what version of python? (Might be a library out there that could help with this depending on OS and version of Python.)

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136734/key-presses-in-python), plenty of answers there for different ways to press keys. (You'll see a lot of them involve `pyautogui`). I also know some people like to use `pywin32` or win32 applications.

Comment: I'm of course using Windows 10 and python 3.11.2

Comment: Try `pywin32` or other win32 applications, and take a look at that SO question post first and see what happens. If lag is the only problem however, I don't think it's worth too much hanging on to if you still can't solve this problem.

Comment: alright, yeah only problem now is that it's kind of lagging is some specific parts sometimes... I mean this time using `pag`'s `keyDown/Up` things got kind of smoother but like for the `c` one, sometimes I almost HAD TO press the right click AND NOT hold it for it to work! and it'd barely work while holding the button down. but holding it was already working on the `enter` one BUT NOT clicking! I believe it kinda needs adjusting, you could also try what I'm doing on the game itself if wanna try it for yourself, to kind of understand what I'm saying.

Comment: That makes sense. Have you tried `pyautogui.hotkey()` yet though? (Pressing two keys at the same time). I think this question is kinda resolved though now :).

Comment: Just tried it out, it was WAY better than the other ones, however I still lost the `c` one a couple of times with it, but now I have a better understanding on how "Old Man Consequences" mechanic works: It actually doesn't accept too many signals at once! stopping the player from trying to spam it until it works, that's why I had this idea minutes ago that we HAVE to press the key and NOT hold it for it to work on Old man, it was a problem from the game mechanic itself. Then I tried the method I found earlier which was `keyboard.press_and_release` which work even better than `pag.hotkey`

Comment: Thanks A LOT for the assist! I'm gonna post an answer on this topic explaining all the different methods and the results I got! :D

Comment: You might want to post it in Discussions to see if anyone has any other advice on the topic. I know for sure that I want to figure out why some things weren't working with your game.

Comment: You've got a point there! so you mean just ask the same question in the discussions tab right? (cause I'm actually new to the website)

Comment: Yep, pretty much. Excited to see what other people think about this, or if there are any other suggestions. (Check out the help center in SO if you're confused about something on this website).

Comment: So, I actually just linked the question to it so I won't have to just ask it again, and yeah it's kind of a wonder that why some of these methods work good and some just not! here's the page: https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/77978629/key-pressing-in-my-python-bot-doesnt-work-properly-in-ultimate-custom-night-gam

Comment: Can't find your page in the discussions. Did you delete it?

Comment: **They** deleted it, idk why this website is sooooooo pushy on these things, you could talk to me on discord btw, although i don't go on too much: pcg1983#0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I better explain the two game mechanics I'm trying to beat in the game, so you can understand the topic much better:

*Old Man Consequences*: Appears at random and player needs to catch his fish by pressing `c` on the keyboard. The fish keeps swimming around the rod and only when it hits rod we can catch it by hitting `c`.

*El Chip*: He shows his ADS at random trying to block your view, you can press the "*skip*" button appeared on the screen OR alternatively hit `enter` on the keyboard to close his AD.

So, in my program I tried hitting the two `c` & `enter` keys at once, which a friend told me it usually wouldn't work, so I decided to use `time.sleep()` to wait for a very short amount of time before pressing the next one. But the method I used to press the keys wasn't a good one, so I found many methods and tried them out and got these results:

**Method 1: pyautogui.press()**

```
import pyautogui as pag
...
pag.press('c')
time.sleep(0.1)
pag.press('enter')
time.sleep(0.1)
```

- This method was the first one that worked for me, but it made the game a bit laggy and didn't catch the fish at the right time or closed the AD fast enough.

**Method 2: pyautogui.keyDown() & .keyUp()**

```
import pyautogui as pag
...
pag.keyDown('c')
time.sleep(0.1)
pag.keyUp('c')
time.sleep(0.1)
pag.keyDown('enter')
time.sleep(0.1)
pag.keyDown('enter')
time.sleep(0.1)
```

- This one work absolutely better than the previous one, but still was laggy and usually lost catching the fish, but always closed the AD although it wasn't so fast.

**Method 3: pyautogui.hotkey()**

```
import pyautogui as pag
...
pag.hotkey('c')
time.sleep(0.1)
pag.hotkey('enter')
time.sleep(0.1)
```

- This worked WAY MUCH better than the other ones, closes the AD so well but lost to the Old man for a couple of times, and also didn't make the game laggy.

**And the final method and the best method that I found it myself:**

**Using keyboard.press_and_release()**

```
keyboard.press_and_release('c')
time.sleep(0.1)
keyboard.press_and_release('enter')
time.sleep(0.1)
```

- This one worked perfect! never lost to the Old Man Consequences nor the El Chip! it closes the AD and catches the fish SO FAST and doesn't interrupt the game or makes it glitchy and laggy!

SO! here's the final result:

```
import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
Keyboard = Controller()
from pynput.mouse import Listener, Button
import pyautogui as pag
import threading
import time
Held = False
def pressEnter():
    while Held:
        keyboard.press_and_release('c')
        time.sleep(0.1)
        keyboard.press_and_release('enter')
        time.sleep(0.1)
def easier_Enter(x, y, butt, held):
    global Held
    Held = held
    if (butt == Button.right) and held:
        threading.Thread(target=pressEnter, daemon=True, args=()).start()
def listener1():
    while True:
        with Listener(on_click=easier_Enter) as l:
            l.join()
def main():
    threading.Thread(target=listener1, daemon=True, args=()).start()
    print("Thread 1 started.")
    while not keyboard.is_pressed('x'):
        try:
            pass
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            getOut()
    getOut()
def getOut():
    print("Exitted.")
    quit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```